# Adding a Third Party Library to Java Applet

Tags: java, applet, classpath, party

I have a Java Applet that needs a 3rd party library, but how do I add the jar to the classpath and reference it to the Java Applet?

My third party library is org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils

Answer (score 4):

Do you want to embed your applet into a website / HTML with the applet tag?

```
<applet code="de.package.AppletClass" 
archive="apache-commons-lang.jar">
</applet>
```

[Deploying With the Applet Tag](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/html.html)

To compile it in console use:

```
javac -classpath C:\dev\YourClass.java C:\dev\3thParty.jar
```

[Compiling the Example Programs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/compiling.html)

Comment: Makes since, but when I compile the .java it comes up with an error saying it can't find that library.

Comment: Your are using an IDE, perhaps Eclipse? If yes, then you have to add the jar to your classpath like this: right click on your project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Add JARs (when your jar is in your project) or Add Externals JARs (when it somewhere on your disk)

Comment: I do it the old fashion way with command prompt :/. I'm guessing you're talking about NetBeans. However, I don't know how to compile a applet in NetBeans.

Comment: I edit/extend my post now for compiling on console with classpath option

Answer (score 4):

Put the other jars in the `Class-Path` property in the manifest.mf and
build an index to the other jars so that the loader won't have to download
a jar unless it really needs it.

Alternatively, you can mention the jars in the archive tag.
In archive tag you can add multiple jars: `archive="MyJar.jar,JarFile1.jar,JarFile2.jar"`

So your archive attribute will be like this `archive="YourProject.jar,commons-lang-2.1.jar"` (Remember that you have to put commons-lang-2.1.jar with YourProject.jar in the same dir on your server.)