# Extending Java with jar that can be used from an Applet

Tags: java, jar, applet, classpath, extend

I want to extend Java with Classes I made myself so that they can be used from Java Applets. I have tried dropping JAR files in the lib and lib/ext folder but they still ain't globally visible.

EDIT: Putting the file in lib/ext works (oops) but not lib. Why?

Is there something more I have to do for Java to load my classes?

I desire this JAR is to be enrolled on the clients using enterprise package management I do know that all clients have to install the JAR archive and that is NOT a problem.

Comment: Did you put them in your source directory then declared in each of them that they use the same source directory ?

Comment: I think your question pretty much duplicates [this one][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6669617/adding-a-third-party-library-to-java-applet

Comment: No it does not. I am not asking how to put it in the manifest.mf classpath. I know how to do that and it is an entirely different thing.