# Set jna library path for an applet

Tags: java, applet, jna

I am trying to run a unsigned applet jar locally.
It uses several jar dependencies and some of those need native dlls. But I do not know how to point those dlls from the applet when deploying it on a browser.
When running using eclipse applet viewer I have set,
 `System.setProperty("jna.library.path", "<path>");`
And it worked fine.

But when I deploy same on IE 10 it gives me the below exception

```
    Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "jna.library.path" "write")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.AWTAppletSecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.setProperty(Unknown Source)
at com.neurotec.samples.SimpleFacesApplication.<init>(SimpleFacesApplication.java:88)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

I want to know where to put those dlls when loading from a browser.
Thanks in advance.

---

UPDATE

---

I have tried adding all the dlls to a new jar file called `nativelibs.jar` and added the entry `<nativelib href="nativelibs.jar"/>` to my applet JNLP file. But the issue is still remains same giving

```
   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'NCore': The specified module could not be found.

at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:194)
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:283)
at com.neurotec.lang.NCore.<clinit>(NCore.java:104)
```

Now the resources tag of my JNLP file is like

```
    <resources>
<!-- Application Resources -->
<j2se version="1.7+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" />
<jar href="myApplet.jar" main="true" />
<nativelib href="nativelibs.jar"/>
</resources>
```

Any body have an idea, what is my mistake?

Comment: Check out this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6669617/adding-a-third-party-library-to-java-applet. Locally, if you are running localhost put them in the same directory as your html and applet files.

Comment: Yes I used the same for my Jar files and they works fine.
But the problem is though I put dlls to the same directory it still gives the error
`Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'NCore': The specified module could not be found.

 at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:194)
 at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:283)
 at com.neurotec.lang.NCore.<clinit>(NCore.java:104)`

Comment: Please post your full JNLP file. Did you set the <security><all-permissions/></security> tag?